# ByRef error when trying to use 2 workbooks as objects

Tags: vba, excel

I need to use 2 workbook objects to run a second sub in my macro. However, there always seems to be a ByRef error for the first sheet i set up. i've come up with an example below. Am i defining the object wrong?

```
Sub test1()
Dim inputwb, outputwb As Workbook

'sets current workbook as inputwb
Set inputwb = ThisWorkbook '<---this sheet causes the ByRef error

'open 2nd workbook
Workbooks.Open (filepath & "\" & filename)
'sets 2nd workbook as outputwb
Set outputwb = ActiveWorkbook

'call next sub
Call test2(inputwb, outputwb)

End Sub

Sub test2(wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook)

MsgBox ("done!")

End Sub
```

Comment: You should declare `inputwb` to be a `Workbook` rather than a `Variant`, i.e `Dim inputwb As Workbook, outputwb As Workbook`.

Comment: Don't rely on ActiveWorkbook. Use `Set outputwb = Workbooks.Open(filepath & "\" & filename)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `Dim` a variable without an `As type` clause, it is set to be a `Variant` by default.  Trying to pass a `Variant` as a parameter to a function/subroutine that is expecting a `Workbook` will cause an error.

Therefore change your `Dim` statement from

```
Dim inputwb, outputwb As Workbook
```

to

```
Dim inputwb As Workbook, outputwb As Workbook
```